# How normalize the table Order Details

Tags: c#, database, database-design, normalization

I have been given an assignment to complete the following task:

[image]

I will be using C# and Sql server to solve the above. However i need an heads up on how many tables i will need since i am completely new to this. I have given this a try, if someone can solve my query its fine or can give me a better alternate solution altogether.
This is what i have tried uptill now.
I have made 3 tables uptill now as shown in image below:

[image]

Now if you notice in the second image i could make Order Number applicable only for one party. However, the issue i am still facing is that when one Party Orders more than one type of Product i will have to generate 2 PO Numbers in the Orders Table.

What is the solution to my issue here? How do i Normalize it further?

P.S. This might sound like a simple question as a simple question because this is my first attempt on Normalization.

Comment: the homework tag is deprecated, so I removed it.

Comment: why the word "Details" in every table? it's unnecessary.

an order has many order items, or "order line items".

Comment: PO attributes should either be in a separate table, or in the same table as the order data. (Not the order detail data.) Same for Ref attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 tables:

1. Partyinformation: id, name, address
2. Productinformation: id, name, price
3. Orderinformation: id: dates etc
4. Orderline: orderID, ProductID, Amount 
   where orderID and ProductID are the foreignkeys into productinformation and orderinformation

Adding products to the (created) order just involves adding an productID and OrderID into [orderline] incrementing the amount when the same product is entered twice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding another table called "Orders".  This table will contain the information that will be the same for the entire order, such as PONumber, PODate, RefDate, PartyID.  Then your OrdersDetail table will contain the information for each product ordered, such as ProductId, Quantity, Rate, Amount, OrderId (FK into the new Order table).

Also, don't make all the data types Text.  Consider using a data type appropriate for the information being stored.  I would also consider either not including Amount or making it a calculated field since it is calculated from other information in the same record (Quantity * Rate).

Further you may consider using a different value other then PONumber as the primary key.  As a general rule the primary key would have no other purpose other then internally identifying record.  I would suggest adding an OrderDetailsId and make that the primary key.

**Edit: (I have added additional information to answer Lohits question below)**

If I understand what you are stating in your question, the Party can have multiple Orders; on each order the party can purchase multiple products.  Therefore there would be a one-to-many relationship between PartyDetails and Order, and a one-to-may relationship between Order and OrderDetail; and a one-to-one relationship between ProductDetails and OrderDetails.  The Party table stores the information about the person purchasing the order.  The Order table stores the information about each order the person places.  The OrderDetails stores the information about each product the person purchases for each order.  And the ProductDetails table stores a list of all products.

Here is a diagram of the data structure as I see it....Mind you it does not have *every* detail in it.  But hopefully it will give you enough to get started.

[image]

Comment: Where does Product ID go? How do i keept track of multiple Products purchased by a Party? I do not understand how the above solves my issue.

Comment: @Lohit.  I have added information to my answer to answer your questions.

Comment: @Lohit.  I am not sure I understand what you mean by ... "However, the issue i am still facing is that when one Party Orders more than one type of Product i will have to generate 2 PO Numbers in the Orders Table.".  In most systems one PO Number per order is needed so that is the way I wrote this.  If this is incorrect please clarify.

Comment: Gene you need to understand that in the OrderDetails table for Every OrderID i can store only 1 ProductID - if you look at the image in question - the user can have MORE than 1 Product in a SINGLE Order- please understand.

Comment: @Lohit  That is why you should split your OrdersDetail table into two tables as I did in my answer.  I created an Orders and OrdersDetail table.  The Orders table will contain ONE row for a single Order.  The OrdersDetail table will contain MULTIPLE rows for a single Order.

Comment: hmmm....I gave the same answer as @lboshuizen but with much more detail.  Guess it is true that sometimes less is more :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this design.  Observe below that there is only 1 PO number per party per order.  This assumes you want to manually supply the PO Number; otherwise, you can use the OrderID as a convenient autogenerated PO Number.

[image]

Comment: What is 'amount' in the Products table supposed to be? Unit price? There also should be a 'price' field in the OrderProduct (aka OrderLines or OrderDetails) table.

Comment: S/he can call it 'OwnSauce', though I wouldn't recommend it.  If s/he wants to add a calculated 'Amount' field to OrderProduct (OrderProduct.Quantity*Product.OwnSauce), s/he could do that too.  Heck, s/he could even add 'Barcode' or even 'OmgIGotPwntByAnUndeadPriest'.  Sky is the limit!  The design does illustrate a normalized structure taking into account 1 PO per order per party.